# Unable to reverse a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Wanted to make reverse string without using the loop
I am getting an array

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str
    .split("")
    .reverse();
}
console.log(reverseString('coder'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `.join("")` after reverse;

Answer (score 2):

`.split()` creates an Array; after doing `.reverse()` it's still an Array.

Use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to return a String:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}
console.log(reverseString('coder'));
```